# I have a problem with my WordPress DB after I tried to install multi-site

Tags: database

I tried to install WordPress Multi-Site. But I ran into some problems with the DB.

```
wp_1_posts: Table 'studioc_editionspanda.wp_1_posts' doesn't exist
wp_1_comments: Table 'studioc_editionspanda.wp_1_comments' doesn't exist
wp_1_links: Table 'studioc_editionspanda.wp_1_links' doesn't exist
wp_1_options: Table 'studioc_editionspanda.wp_1_options' doesn't exist
wp_1_postmeta: Table 'studioc_editionspanda.wp_1_postmeta' doesn't exist
wp_1_terms: Table 'studioc_editionspanda.wp_1_terms' doesn't exist
wp_1_term_taxonomy: Table 'studioc_editionspanda.wp_1_term_taxonomy' doesn't exist
wp_1_term_relationships: Table 'studioc_editionspanda.wp_1_term_relationships' doesn't exist
wp_1_commentmeta: Table 'studioc_editionspanda.wp_1_commentmeta' doesn't exist
```

What do I do?

Comment: *"I tried to install"*, and how was that?

Comment: WordPress installed well. It's when I followed the instructions for multi-site setup that I received a error message with the DB.

Answer (score 6):

You most probably only added one of the following in your `wp-config.php` file thinking they were the same, as [m73mitchell](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/some-tables-not-getting-created-in-wordpress-setup-tutorial) and I had done:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
```

I couldn't find any documentation why they have this counterintuitive setup, but just add the one you missed and it should work.

Comment: Thanks this worked!

Comment: And for me thanks a lot! I now feel pretty stupid about the amount of time this took me to solve..